# What is this plant name with narrow leaves and red nerve?

Tags: houseplants, ornamental-plant

I bought this plant recently. It has narrow leaves and red nerves in middle.
The seller told it’s an ornamental plant but not sure of it’s name.

What is it’s name?

[image: Pot plant with long thin leaves]

Comment: Have you used leaf snap before? There are apps out there that can identify a plant